# Program gives timeout after using long value

Tags: c

In this code using C, I want to check for the `'a'` but, after entering the long value for `n`, I am getting a timeout error; and it is happening for long values only.

```
long repeatedString(char* s, long n)
{
    long len=strlen(s);
    long c=0;
    char* str=(char*) malloc(100000000);
   
    strcpy(str,s);
    
    if(len==1)
    {
        if(s[0]=='a')
        {
            c=n;
        }
    }
    else {
        while(len<n)
        {   
            strcat(str,s);
            len=strlen(str);    
        }

        for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(str[i]=='a')
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you want others to read it.

Comment: `malloc(100000000);` may be a bit overdone. Fix your algorithm to use exactly what you need.

Comment: Could you give some explicit parameters that when passed cause the timeout issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to see how you arrived at this code, but it looks like you're trying to count the occurrences of the character `a` in a string `str` of `n` characters made by repeating a string `s`.

This can be done without actually creating the string `str` at all. Just calculate two values: `p = n / len` and `q = n % len`, where len is the length of s. The number of times `a` appears in `str` is equal to `p` times the number of `a`s in `s`, plus the number of `a`s in the first `q` characters of `s`. You can calculate this very quickly.

I should also point out that "magic numbers" like 100000000 are best avoided when programming. In any case, the maximum number of bytes you *actually* need (if using your original method) is equal to `n + strlen(s)`. So you could have used that instead.

Here's some (minimally tested) code that should do the same job a lot faster. I factored out a `charCount()` function to count the occurrences of a character in the first `len` bytes of a string.

```
long charCount(char *s, char c, long len) {
    long n = 0;
    while (*s && len--) {
        if (*s++ == c) n++;
    }
    return n;
}

long repeatedString(char* s, long n)
{
    long len = strlen(s);
    long p = n / len, q = n % len;
    return charCount(s, 'a', len) * p + charCount(s, 'a', q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is at least `O(n*log(n))`, which can cause the run time to take quite a long time. This is caused by your repeated calls to `strcat()`.

We could rewrite your algorithm in `O(n)` like this, which would be much faster:

```
long repeatedString(const char* s, long n) {
  long s_length = strlen(s);
  long c = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (s[i % s_length] == 'a')
      c++;
  return c;
}
```

We could improve this to `O(strlen(s))` as well, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

(On repl.it, with the arguments `s = "abc", n = 1000000`, your solution takes 6 seconds, and the suggested solution here takes 0 seconds)

Comment: Sir,can we use this logic for n=736778906400

Comment: I'd probably recommend r3mainer's solution. His is O(s.len()), where mine is O(n).